# Meteor - escape quoted text (svg) stored in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, svg, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'd like to store an svg inside a MongoDB record with Meteor. However, when I output it with Blaze like so:

```
{{svgFile}}
```

...it is quoted, and the quoted text is displayed instead of the svg image. How can I just display the raw contents of it instead of the quoted text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the triple bracket syntax to render HTML (or SVG) strings as DOM elements :

```
{{{svgFile}}}
```